# Code that throw Deprecated warnings works correctly, but updated code does not work?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, deprecation-warning

I am using the following code as part of a function on my site. This is a snippet - of course the function contains a lot more information, however that is not relevant to my current issue:

```php
$get_product_id = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    $get_title = $get_product_id->get_name();
    $get_cat = $get_product_id->get_categories(); // FAILING
    $get_tag = $get_product_id->get_tags(); // FAILING
    $output = '';
```

As things stand, all 5 lines of code work correctly and allow me to display on the front end, all the correct information I require, however in my `debug.php` file, I am getting the following errors:

> PHP Deprecated:  WC_Product::get_categories is **deprecated** since version 3.0! Use wc_get_product_category_list instead.

and

> PHP Deprecated:  WC_Product::get_tags is **deprecated** since version 3.0! Use wc_get_product_tag_list instead.

I understand this is because I am using outdated PHP, but the errors leave me with two questions:

1. Is it bad to ignore debug errors if the code appears to work correctly? I noticed some of the third-party plugins my site uses also return the odd debug error (some of the plugin come from very reputable sources too)!
2. Upon attempting to use the new (correct) code, I was unable to get any post values and kept getting empty an empty return. What do I actually need to change to get my code working correctly and without it giving me debug errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Is it bad to ignore debug errors?** I'm not going to answer good or bad, but debug errors generally mean that something larger might be broken or not behaving correctly. Further, your debug warnings are deprecation warnings, which are a specific case of warning to be aware of. Some/many/most libraries have a deprecation schedule where in version `X` they'll deprecate a feature and in version `X+1` they'll complete remove it. Whether WooCommerce will do this I can't say, but you should assume that it could happen at any given moment and take action.
2. **How to fix.** If you look at the source code for the [`get_tags`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-legacy-abstract-wc-legacy-product.html) (line 386 as of today) you'll see that they are actually using the new function already, so you should be able to swap it in directly.

```php
    public function get_tags( $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' ) {
        wc_deprecated_function( 'WC_Product::get_tags', '3.0', 'wc_get_product_tag_list' );
        return wc_get_product_tag_list( $this->get_id(), $sep, $before, $after );
    }
```

So instead of:

```php
$get_tag = $get_product_id->get_tags(); // FAILING
```

You should be able to just use:

```php
$get_tag = wc_get_product_tag_list(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did add the 'get_the_ID()' to the final line of your code, but after slapping myself on the head, I thank you for giving me the correct answer! It works perfectly!

Comment: Note: Should be from a defined product id like: `$get_tag = wc_get_product_tag_list( $product_id );`

Comment: @LionHeart-Nerd, as LoicTheAztec pointed out, it is probably more correct to pass the ID, so I've accepted your edit. If you don't, WordPress will fall back to grabbing the `post` from `get_post()` so it should be safe to omit while inside of the loop, but better safe then sorry.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Why would ``$get_tag = wc_get_product_tag_list( $get_product_id );`` not work correctly?

Comment: @LionHeart-Nerd, they are saying that it *would* work. I think you are both on the same page.

Comment: @LionHeart-Nerd I just said the product id must be passed to the function, otherwise nothing is displayed…